# Deriving $e^{ix} = 1 + ix + \frac{(ix)^2}{2!}+...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know how to prove equation:

$$e = \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^x$$

How can I now derive the series:

$$e^{ix} = 1 + ix + \frac{(ix)^2}{2!}+\frac{(ix)^3}{3!}+...$$

Those two seem very similar to me...

Comment: thats not eulers constant.. it's bernoullis constant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the binomial theorem on the following limit:

$$e^z = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{z}{x} \right)^x$$

i.e.,

$$\begin{align} \left( 1 + \frac{z}{x} \right)^x &= 1 + \frac{x}{1!} \frac{z}{x}  + \frac{x (x-1)}{2!} \left (\frac{z}{x} \right )^2 + \frac{x (x-1) (x-2)}{3!} \left (\frac{z}{x} \right )^3 + \ldots \\ &= 1 + \frac{z}{1!} + \frac{z^2}{2!} \left ( 1-\frac{1}{x} \right ) + \frac{z^3}{3!} \left ( 1-\frac{1}{x} \right ) \left ( 1-\frac{2}{x} \right ) + \ldots \\ \end{align} $$

As $x \rightarrow \infty$, the product terms approach $1$.  Therefore

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{z}{x} \right)^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{k!} = e^z$$

Now, for $z=i x$,

$$e^{i x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(i x)^k}{k!} = 1 + i x + \frac{(i x)^2}{2!} + \ldots$$

Comment: Fist i have to ask you how did u get $e^z = \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{z}{x} \right)^x$ out of $e = \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^x$?

Comment: I didn't.  I was just answering your question about getting $e^{i x}$, and I was using the simplest way I knew how from a similar limit.  I proved to you that the former equation in your comment is true, then I applied $z=i x$ to answer your question.

Comment: Is there any way you could supply a proof for $e^z = \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{z}{x} \right)^x$ ?

Comment: Isn't that what I did?  I am confused.

Comment: @71GA, that limit formula is usually given as the _definition_ of $e^x$. You can also define $f(x)=e^x$ as the function such that $f'(x)=f(x)$ and $f(0)=1$. You can divide the interval $[0,x]$ into n parts, and use step along it using euler integration to estimate $f(x)$. You wind up with that exact formula, and then you take the limit as n goes to infinity. (not too rigorous, but intuitive!) Maybe I should write something up on this... I haven't found it online (which is weird, because I read it online years ago).

Comment: @rigordonma You start with the equation $e^z = \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{z}{x} \right)^x$ which i have no reason to believe in because you have not prooven it and to me (a newbie) it has no background. What you have shown is how to evolve the mentioned equation into a series $1 + i x + \frac{(i x)^2}{2!} + \ldots$.

Comment: @71GA: let me see, perhaps you mean prove it from $e^z = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left [ \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^x \right ]^z= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left [ \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^z \right ]^x = = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{z}{x} \right)^x $ because of the binomial theorem.

Comment: How do you justify the interchange of the limit and the summation?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: I don't follow you.  You mean how do I justify taking the limit of the individual terms in my sum?  Each individual term in the sum has a limit that is well-defined, so the limit of the sum is the sum of the individual limits of the terms.

Comment: That is not true in general.  Usually you need to invoke the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem to say something like that, but I don't see how to use it here.

Comment: See, for example, [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123738/limit-summation-interchanging).

Comment: @AntonioVargas: OK, thanks for pointing ths out, although I'm not exactly sure how much use this is to the OP.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy If you would write somthing about that it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

If we are allowed to use calculus,

let $$z=1+\frac y{1!}+\frac{y^2}{2!}+\frac{y^3}{3!}+\frac{y^4}{4!}+\cdots$$

So, $$\frac{dz}{dy}=0+1+\frac y{1!}+\frac{y^2}{2!}+\frac{y^3}{3!}+\frac{y^4}{4!}+\cdots=z$$

$$\implies \frac{dz}z=dy$$

Integrating both sides, $\log z=y+c$

For $y=0,z=1\implies c=\log1-0=0\implies \log z=y\iff z=e^y$