# Proof for $e^z = \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{z}{x} \right)^x$

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Q1:** Could someone provide a proof for this equation (please focus on this question):

$$e^z = \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{z}{x} \right)^x$$

**Q2:** Is there any corelationn between above equation and the equation below (this would benefit me a lot because i at least know how to proove this one):

$$e = \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^x$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294855/deriving-eix-1-ix-fracix22

Comment: For $Q2$, set $z=1$, $e^1 = e$

Comment: Thank you. How about proof for **Q1**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y=x/z$. Then 
$$
\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{z}{x} \right)^x
=
\lim \limits_{y \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{y} \right)^{yz}
=
\left(\lim \limits_{y \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{y} \right)^{y}\right)^z 
= e^z
$$

But note that this assumes that you have a definition of $a^x$ and know that $a^{xy}=(a^x)^y$ and that $x\mapsto a^x$ is continuous.

Comment: And note that $z$ is considered as *constant* while $x$ varies, tending to $\infty$, hence $x/z\to\infty$, too.

Comment: Nicely shown but I still need anwser to Q1.

Comment: @lhf, how do you get `y -> inf` here? If z is negative, won't y -> -inf when x -> inf?