# How to find the value of this limit? $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac x{x+1}\right)^x.$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I evaluate this limit?

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\dfrac x{x+1}\right)^x.$$

Hm I can't take this limit. I know what I have to use, but I can't. Sorry about this. Who can do it for example?

Comment: "I know what I have to use". What is that, then?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295584/proof-for-ez-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-left-1-fraczx-rig?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295584/proof-for-ez-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-left-1-fraczx-rig?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\Bigl(\frac x{1+x}\Bigr)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\Bigl(\frac{x-1}x\Bigr)^{x-1}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\Bigl(1-\frac1x\Bigr)^{x-1}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\Bigl(1-\frac1x\Bigr)^x\Big/\Bigl(1-\frac1x\Bigr)=e^{-1}/\,1=1/e$$

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(x)=\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^x$. Find the limit
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\ln(f(x)).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Suince nobody wrote the expression I was thinking of, I will:

$$\frac x{x+1}=\frac1{\frac{x+1}x}=\frac1{1+\frac1x}\implies\left(\frac x{x+1}\right)^x=\frac1{\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\frac1e$$

Comment: This is basically multiplying with $1=\frac{1/x}{1/x}$

Comment: Well, in fact it is **exactly** the same. Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $(\frac{x}{x+1})^x=(1-\frac{1}{x+1})^{x+1}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x+1}}$ and use $\lim_{x\to \infty}(1+\frac 1x)^x=e$