# Calculate the following: $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{e^n+(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, exponential-function

So here it is: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{e^n+(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}}~~~(n \in \mathbb{N})$$

I tried to use the Squeeze theorem like so:
$e \leq \sqrt[n]{e^n+(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}} \leq e \sqrt[n]{2}$

And if that is true, the limit is simply $e$.

Only that, for it to be true, I first need to prove that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2} \leq e^n$. So how do I prove it?

Alternatively, how else can I calculate the limit?
I prefer to hear about the way I tried, though.

Thanks

Comment: It's known that $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n < e$. What you want should follow easily from that.

Comment: Yes,  it is true that $(1+1/n)^n$ is increasing.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295584/proof-for-ez-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-left-1-fraczx-rig

Comment: @GuyFsone  You're flooding the review queue with questionable claims of duplicity.  Knock it off.

Comment: taking another post an rise to power n and take the nth root . id this not a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$
(1+u)^b = \exp(b\log (1+u)) \le \exp(bu)
$$
when $b>0$, because $\log(1+u)\le u$.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have the theorem that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n \le e$ for any natural number $n$? If so, then you do indeed have the inequality you want, and the rest of your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You want $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n < e$, i.e. $e^{1/n} > 1 + \frac{1}{n}$. This is true because

$$e^{1/n} = 1 +\frac{1}{n} +\frac{1}{2n^2} + \cdots > 1 +\frac{1}{n}$$