# What is the limit of $((x-1)/x)^x$ as $x$ goes to infinity?

Tags: limits, bootstrap-sampling

I came across this limit when considering bootstrapping since $1 - ((x-1)/x)^x$ is the probability that observation $j$ from a sample of size $x$ does appears in a bootstrap sample also of size $x$. In other words, one minus this quantity is the probability of picking $j$ when choosing $x$ elements from $\{ 1, \ldots, x\}$ with replacement.

Using a computer, this limit appears to converge to approximately $0.3678611$ (this is the value for $x=10000$ to 7 d.p). I thought to try applying L'Hôpital's rule, knowing that the derivative of $x^x$ is $x^x(ln(x) + 1)$, but I could not make any progress.

Comment: Rewrite as $(1-1/x)^x$, which is the standard limit for...

Comment: So $(1+1/x)^x$ is the standard limit for $e$, I'm not seeing how to get to $(1-1/x)^x$

Comment: Oh okay, $1-1/x = x-1/x$ whereas $1+1/x = x+1/x$

Comment: @ChrisRussell In fact $\lim (1+\frac1u)^u=e$ here consider $u=-x$ so we have $\lim ((1-\frac1x)^{-x})^{-1}=(e)^{-1}$

Comment: @Soheil, This substitution is inappropriate to use, since we are using $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ and $\lim_{u\to\infty}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof for $e^z = \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{z}{x} \right)^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295584/proof-for-ez-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-infty-left-1-fraczx-rig)

Comment: I don't like citing results as though they are magic trick but ... $\lim_{x\to \infty} (1 +\frac k x)^x = e^k$.  SO if $k = -1$ abracadabra $\lim_{x\to \infty} (\frac {x-1}x)^x = e^{-1} = \frac 1e$.  ... uh... I guess it's not so bad if I take Soheil's comment.  But $u=\frac xk$ then $\lim (1+\frac kx)^x = \lim(1 +\frac 1u)^{ku} = e^k$.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have
$$
\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^x
 = \left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^{-x} = \left(1+\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^{-x}
 \to e^{-1}
$$